# In django2 how do I set a different default for new objects and legacy objects respectively?

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I'd like to add a new field to an existing model. For backwards compatibility reasons, I want to have two defaults:

- One which is set for legacy objects by a migration
- One which is used for new instances of the model

I can see that the code for adding fields in migrations is pretty simple:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='queue',
        name='permission_name',
        field=models.CharField(help_text='Name used in the django.contrib.auth permission system', max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='Django auth permission name', blank=True),
    ),
]
```

However, I don't see where I should add the legacy default.

PS: Truthfully speaking, I don't want the legacy default in the migration at all. I would much prefer it to be set in `models.py` so that it is clear to people reading the code what is going on. But I presume it has to be in a migration and I will leave a comment in `models.py` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way to specify a legacy default in `models.py`, however this can be accomplished fairly easily with migrations.

For example, if you add a new migration, `secret_key` to the model ticket, you would create two migrations for this new field. One migration adds the field as a null able field and subsequent uses `RunPython` to set the legacy default.

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import helpdesk.models

def clear_secret_keys(apps, schema_editor): # set the legacy default
    Ticket = apps.get_model("helpdesk", "Ticket")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    for ticket in Ticket.objects.using(db_alias).all():
         ticket.secret_key='<legacy-default>'
         ticket.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('helpdesk', '0017_default_owner_on_delete_null'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='ticket',
            name='secret_key',
            field=models.CharField(default='<default-for-new-objects>', max_length=36, null=True, verbose_name='Secret key needed for viewing/editing ticket by non-logged in users'),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(clear_secret_keys),
    ]
```

If you don't want your field to be nullable, you need to create a second migration which alters the field to be non-nullable:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import helpdesk.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('helpdesk', '0018_ticket_secret_key'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='ticket',
            name='secret_key',
            field=models.CharField(default='<default-for-new-objects>', max_length=36, verbose_name='Secret key needed for viewing/editing ticket by non-logged in users'),
        ),
    ]
```

Writing out this answer it occurs to me that there is another way to do this, also with two migrations, and that is by first setting the legacy default and following up with the default for new objects:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import helpdesk.models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('helpdesk', '0017_default_owner_on_delete_null'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='ticket',
            name='secret_key',
            field=models.CharField(default='<legacy-default>', max_length=36, null=True, verbose_name='Secret key needed for viewing/editing ticket by non-logged in users'),
        ),
    ]
```

If you don't want your field to be nullable, you need to create a second migration which alters the field to be non-nullable:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import helpdesk.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('helpdesk', '0018_ticket_secret_key'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='ticket',
            name='secret_key',
            field=models.CharField(default=helpdesk.models.mk_secret, max_length=36, verbose_name='Secret key needed for viewing/editing ticket by non-logged in users'),
        ),
    ]
```

Both of these methods should work even for dynamic defaults. For example, in this case the default for new objects is a method called `helpdesk.models.mk_secret` which generates a unique uuid for all newly created objects.